# Less/Meteor treating media queries as variables?

Tags: meteor, less, media-queries

I'm working with both Less and Meteor for the first time. Everything is very cool, except I'm stymied trying to get media queries to work.

I have a series of media queries structured like this one:

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */ 
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {   
@columns: 12;
  .full() {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container(){
    .center(12);
  }
  .main-col() {
    .column(9);
    .push(0);
  }
  .side-col(){
    .column(3);
    float:right;
  }
  .nested-left-col(){
     .nested-left(6) 
   }
  .nested-right-col(){
     .nested-right(3);
  }
}
```

But when the css is compiled, all I get is this:

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
```

Oddly, media queries that contain nothing but comments compile as expected:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

I'm pretty sure that these media queries are being treated as variables that never get called.

Am I simply doing it wrong? Is there something incredibly obvious that I'm missing? I've been searching for an answer for half an hour, but can't find anyone with the same issue. That kind of suggests that I'm missing the obvious, but maybe I have run into something unusual.

Comment: Your code contains nothing but [parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) which do nothing unless invoked. Thus the empty output is expected.

Comment: When I have that code outside the query they are invoked, but when I put them in they aren't?

Comment: See [Scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope). Each `@media` block has its own scope so mixins defined inside a `@media` block are visible only in that block. (I.e. mixin calls outside of a `@media` block do not invoke mixins defined inside of it). Probably a slightly more expanded example of what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I'd originally been approaching these mixins differently and was going to make them parametric, so they had the (). After I changed my approach I didn't bother to remove the ()s because it worked fine to pass no values to them as long as I was just invoking them directly in the CSS for layout testing. But when I moved them into the media queries, they no longer were invoked and I got the blank output.

Removing the ()s so they were no longer evaluated as parametric fixed it.

I'm still getting no output from the @columns variable, but what I'm trying to do there is redeclare a global value. I kind of expected that wouldn't work anyway, so I'll find a different approach.

Thanks. Much appreciated.